# uiswipegesturerecognizer to pass from detail views of an UITableview IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have an `UITableView` to display some elements, when I click in each cell I can see its detailViewController. I would like to pass from one detailViewController to the next making an `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to left, and if I make `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to right, get back to the tableView.

Thank you

Comment: correct me if im wrong but a UITableViewCell doesn't have a detail view but a detail text label

Comment: No, sorry. I mean when I click in each item I can watch a new DetailViewController

Answer (score 0):

Add the swipe recognizer to your view or tableview

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToNextView)];

    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft]; //Add to the view or tableview or whatever
```

Add the method

```
- (void)goToNextView
{
     YourViewController *vc =
     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdendifier"];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Do the same to go back but instead of using push, use pop